# What besides YUM will break in CentOS 7 when switching /usr/bin/python to point to python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos7, python-2.x, rhel7

I have a request to switch a CentOS 7 machine from using Python 2.7 as the defualt Python version to Python 3. I know YUM works with Python 2.7 and not 3, however what else would break when doing this that I am not aware of?

Comment: Why would anyone want to do this? You can install python 3 along side python 2. You can install it for specific users. You can create virtual environments. Take whoever has this bizarre request and install, say, anaconda python 3 in their account and let them worry about any problems.

Comment: The environment uses both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 installed side by side, however it is requested that the service daemon that runs builds runs using Python 3.6 by default and be able to simply run "python script.py" and it default to 3.6.

Comment: Also, I am well aware that you wouldn't normally do this, however I wanted more of a reason to tell the client that this isn't the way to go as it will break several other things including YUM, but I wanted to know what else might break.